# WPF listbox with canvas only showing last item

Tags: wpf, canvas, listbox

I have a ListBox with a Canvas as ItemsPanel.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid  Margin="0,2,2,2" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
                <Rectangle Cursor="Hand" Fill="AliceBlue"
                        MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown"
                        MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove"
                        MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
         x:Name="listBox"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}">


    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The problem is that whenever I add a new item to Items, which Listbox is binding to, it only shows that new item on screen. All previous items in the list are not shown. I can see that all the items are indeed in the Items list, and ListBoxItems are added to the visual tree. But I cannot see them. Only the last item added.

This is what it looks like running (only ever one item is shown)

[image]

This is what it looks like in designer and how it should look like running

[image]

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

The code the designer uses is this

```
public class DrawingPanelViewModelMockup: DrawingPanelViewModel
{
    public DrawingPanelViewModelMockup()
    {
        //Pc subclasses DrawingComponent
        var pc = new Pc();
        pc.Name = "PC";
        pc.X = 20;
        pc.Y = 40;
        pc.Width = 100;
        pc.Height = 50;
        Items.Add(pc);

        ... 

    }
}
```

And the real code that adds to Items (ObservableCollection) is this. It's part of a Drag-n-drop operation.

```
var comp = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DrawingComponent).FullName) as DrawingComponent;
var drawingPanelVm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DrawingPanelViewModel>();
comp.X = mousePos.X;
comp.Y = mousePos.Y;
comp.Width = 100;
comp.Height = 50;
drawingPanelVm.Items.Add(comp);
```

Comment: Is Items a List or an ObservableCollection? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: You should also show the code that actually adds items. How does it differ from the design mode code?

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's an ObservableCollection, please see my update

Comment: @Clemens Added the code for adding in design and running

Comment: How are you ruling out the possibility that there are two instances of `DrawingPanelViewModel`? Another possibility I'd look into is that maybe `comp` is the same object every time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm using MVVM light and ServiceLocator. But just to make sure I've just tried setting a breakpoint in the DrawingPanelViewModel constructor and it only got hit once

Comment: Thanks for checking the constructor. So much for that idea. How do the `DrawingComponent` instances get created? After you've dropped a few of them, set a breakpoint in the drop code. Are there multiple items in `Items`, and do they all have the same property values? Or different values? Or is there just one item, or what?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think you might be onto something. All the items have same values in all properties, x, y, width, height... Somehow I must be adding the same item !?!?

Comment: What happens in the code that puts the `DrawingComponent` into the data object when you start the drag operation?

Comment: @EdPlunkett you're my hero! When I start the drag operation it uses the same object in the DoDragDrop method. I need to make some sort of new object in the receiving end. If you make an answer the tick is yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML works fine, and you've confirmed that there's only one copy of the viewmodel created, hence only one `Items` collection, and the first drop works.

Looking at your code, what jumps out at me is this line:

```
var comp = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DrawingComponent).FullName) as DrawingComponent;
```

That's not creating a `DrawingComponent`; it's pulling one out of a hat that something else put it into. I'd put a breakpoint in there and see if you're actually getting multiple items in `Items`, but they're all the same actual object instance, with the same property values.

Or I'd just go straight to the code that *starts* the drag, and make sure you're creating a new `DrawingComponent` every time -- or else create a clone each time on the drop end. Doing it on the drag end seems better though, because then you can drag different subclasses of `DrawingComponent` from different sources and  the drop code doesn't need to worry about it.